# Wordpress Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

Apologies for the undetailed description on my last question. I installed wordpress with Jevelin Theme on linux server, its a really basic setup, i had'nt edited any code whatsoever with the setup, or added any unecessary plugins, it was working straight out the box untill i have recently got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in
>   /tmp/theme_temp_setupgwHCl7 on line 2.

I have tried to do the following apon reading some other comments with the same problem:

1. Delete current theme (no effect)
2. Rename plugins folder (no effect)

I connot even access wp-admin upon deleting the theme. Get the same error. I cannot locate tmp/theme_temp on my server either. I see no such directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated. ------

Comment: you expect us to do what exactly; guess?

Comment: Installing Psychic Debugging Module - please wait...

Comment: Apologies for that last comment Fred, it's just very frustrating as i have never come accross this before. I have tried to give a more detailed question.

Answer (score -1):

I'll guess you've embedded html inside a  block in the offending file (somewhere near the top).

You *really* need to provide a much more detailed problem description to get any real help.

Comment: I have not touched a file called  /tmp/theme_temp_setupwQZaeh or edited any other template files. This is why i am asking if anyone would have some advise. If i look in my tmp folder, there is no file called theme_temp.

Comment: The site was working 100% and i hadn't touched a thing untill the other day this error appeared.

Comment: I am running Wordpress with the latest versions of PHP and SQL on linux server if this helps.